# Perl Pattern matching and appending

Tags: perl

In perl I want to achieve the following translation:

```
stmt1; gosub xyz;
```

to

```
stmt1; xyz();
```

How can I do this?

Comment: See http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/Perl/sandtr.html

Comment: I tried to split the line using ";" as dilimiter and then if the pattern was found I tried to replace it.

$line =~ m/$pattern_gosub(.*?)(\;)*$/;
$line =~ s/$pattern_gosub//;
$line =~ s/$1/$1\(\)\;/;

But this did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers already given has provided the approximative answer, this will deal with your edge cases (missing semi-colons, additional clauses after semi-colons).

```
perl -plwe 's/\bgosub\s+([^;]+)/$1()/g'
```

It will match any sequence of characters after the `gosub` keyword followed by whitespace that are "not semi-colon" and remove them. I also added the `/g` global modifier, as it seems likely that you'd want to do all replacements possible on a single line. Note the use of word boundary `\b` to prevent partial matches, e.g. not replace `legosub`.

If the word boundary is not sufficient, e.g. it will replace `1.gosub` because `.` causes a break between word characters, you can use a negative lookbehind instead:

```
perl -plwe 's/(?<![^;\s])gosub\s+([^;]+)/$1()/g'
```

This requires that any character before `gosub` is not anything except semi-colon or whitespace. Note that the double negation also allows for non-matches (beginning of line).

Comment: Thank you so much. It works for all the conditions that I have come across

Comment: @user1912265 You're welcome. You know that you can mark an answer as "accepted" by clicking the check mark next to it, if you feel it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Run from the command line on the file you want to edit (replaceing file.ext):

```
perl -i.bk -pe 's/gosub (.*?);/$1()/g' file.ext
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
There are few lines in which the semi-colon is missing, what changes do I have to make in that case?

Comment: Well you need something that will count as the end to your function name. If it's just a newline then you can use that: `perl -i.bk -pe 's/gosub (.*?)\n/$1()\n/g' file.ext`

Comment: It is possible the there might be another statement following the gosub. Sorry for not specifying that initially. So the line can be stmt1; gosub foo; stmt2; or it can also be just stmt1; gosub foo

Comment: Why doesnt the following work?
            $line =~ s/gosub (.*?)[;\n\s]/$1();/;

Comment: Make the last part optional by adding a question mark. $line =~ s/gosub (.*?)[;\n\s]?/$1();/

Comment: When I tried doing that gosub foo; stmt1 was converted to foo;stmt1(); but the expected output was foo();stmt1

Answer (score 0):

```
my $str = 'stmt1; gosub xyz;';
$str    =~ s/gosub (.*?);?/$1();/;

print $str;
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. There are few lines in which the semi-colon is missing, what changes do I have to make in that case?

Comment: I add ;? to regexp, it should help